# How to register customer in magento 2 with Address data using API?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

**Register customer** in Magento 2 with **Address** data using API

- I am able to register customer without Address Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Register Customer using API**

> webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
<service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
<resources>
    <resource ref="anonymous"/>
</resources>
</route>
```

url `http://<magento-host>/rest/V1/customers`

> url action :: POST

**Body > raw > JSON(application/json)**

```
{
"customer":{
    "email":"Test@example.com",
    "firstname":"Aditya",
    "lastname":"Shah",
    "websiteId":"1",
    "addresses":[
        {
            "customer_id":"1",
            "firstname":"Aditya",
            "lastname":"Shah",
            "company":"ABC Manufacturing",
            "telephone":"555-555-5555",
            "city":"Boston",
            "region":"Massachusetts",
            "postcode":"02115",
            "country_id":"US",
            "street":[
                "404 Main Street",
                "PO Box 321"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
 "password": "Account@123"
}
```

Comment: I can create new account using this in magento 2.4 but when I try to login I get 401 unauthorized. Same if I try to login on website, any ideea why?